# Unable to load pages in web browsers

Tags: 11.10, internet, browser

Using Ubuntu 11.10, I am having a problem browsing web pages. I tested my connection by pinging different sites. All of them reply to me, but my browsers do not work. The problem is not specific to one browser, as I have tested both Firefox and Chromium.

This is the `wget` output when run in Terminal:

```
wget ubuntu.com
Resolving ubuntu.com... 91.189.94.156 Connecting to ubuntu.com|91.189.94.156|:80
```

No error is raised.  What do I have to do?

Thanks for every bodies answers.

My problem was from IPV6 activat.

Open the firefox browser and type:

```
about:config
```

Press accept button with the text `I'll be careful, I promiss!`

then enter IPV6 in filter field. just one entry remain in list with text `network.dns.disableIPv6`. Right click on this and press Toggle. the value field must be true.

After, take logout and logon again.

Now test again!

I did the above stream.It got solve for some minutes but the problem started again.

So now I have not the page loading in my ubuntu.

Comment: Which type of connection is your using?

Comment: And whats your connection speed
(use system monitor)
try to install apps from ubutu software centre is it possible?

Comment: I am using wireless connection and nothing done here. Update, upgrade, browsing page and etc.

Comment: What kind of devices do You use for connection? Do You have proper drivers installed?

Comment: Could you start `wget http://www.ubuntu.com/` from a terminal and confirm that you get an `index.html` in the current working directory? If not, please post the appearing messages, we might catch a hint of the problem.

Comment: I was connecting tile 3 days ago and made no change.Every thing seems to be Ok but this does not works.

Comment: wget ubuntu.com
.................
Resolving ubuntu.com... 91.189.94.156
Connecting to ubuntu.com|91.189.94.156|:80

Comment: ping google.com
.........................
PING google.com (173.194.41.83) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr08s01-in-f19.1e100.net (173.194.41.83): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=148 ms

Comment: ping ubuntu.com

PING ubuntu.com.................. (91.189.94.156) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vostok.canonical.com (91.189.94.156): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=158 ms

Comment: It is interesting. I have ping of the sites but I can not access them. And have no proxy and no special configuration. and because firefox and chromum, both of them have problem so the browsers hav not common problem at list! :S

Comment: I forgot to say that my friend has fedora16 and he has this problem so!

Comment: @Amin I think we'd profit from the output like: http://pastie.org/3373278 Could you pastie yours, or include it in the question?

Comment: what is this and where can I find my own?

Comment: This is the output of the `wget` command above. Pastie is a free web service to paste source code/output of a command (too large to fit into a message). http://pastie.org/about/ Alternatively you can edit your question and include the output.

Comment: @Amin If I understand correctly it cuts off at connecting to the host. Could you run `sudo ufw status` and confirm it is `Status: inactive` to cross out the default firewall?

Comment: because of the hosts are replying, can we get this result that we are connected to the host?

Comment: If you did not get the `... connected.` text, I'm afraid not.

Comment: The result was --> Status: inactive
.................
what is it's mean?

Comment: @Amin That means you do not have the „Uncomplicated Firewall” enabled. Could you tell us more about the network you're connecting to (eg. university / corporate, etc.)? Is that administered by yourself or some other person?

Comment: It's administrator is myself. I have bought a wireless modem and ADSL service.

Comment: Have you installed the latest kernel update (it is `3.0.0-16.28` for me)? If so, could you reboot and select an older kernel version from `Previous linux versions menu`? To check your current version start `uname -a` from terminal.

Comment: I was connecting before with this kernel state and other condition.I made no change on my system.So I thing this problem is out of my system configuration.

Comment: Ok. I'm starting to run out of guesses. If it is neither a driver issue (worked with the kernel), nor a firewall issue (does not seem to be enabled), not even wireless filtering issue (works under windows with the same adapter), and definitely not a browser problem (since wget does not work)... What could it be? Well I'd update the question with the gathered information and see if someone more knowledgeable finds the answer. You should also include the output of `lspci`, `uname -a`.

Comment: uname -a --->  3.0.0-12-generic #20-ubuntu SMP

Comment: I set the result in main question

Comment: @Amin One thing popped into my mind as I was walking into work: you could try to boot from a Live CD and test from there. I assume the Live environment worked for you when you first installed Ubuntu. Since it is considered an untouched system it crosses out any problem regarding your installation and leaves only the wireless router (or your adapter / or any transmission problem).

Comment: @Amin Please edit your question to put the new information you've found in it. Don't post your reply directly as a comment.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was related to IPv6.

1. In Firefox's URL bar type: `about:config`
2. Click the button with the text `I'll be careful, I promise!`
3. Enter `IPv6` in the filter field. Just one entry named `network.dns.disableIPv6` should remain in the list.
4. Right click on this and press `Toggle`. The value must be `true`.

After that, logout and login again, and it should work.

Comment: Simply restarting Firefox after doing this also seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Are you sure that is a browser problem?**
   Do you have a proxy? Check your browser
   Firefox -> Modify -> Precerences -> Advanced -> Connection
2. **Do you have a trasparent proxy?**
   Check with this:
   http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test
3. **Does your ISP block http traffic?** 
   You say that ICMP works, check ftp, ssh and other protocols

Comment: I was using my internet tile 3 days ago.this problem raised newly. I have no proxy and can ping every site I want.

Comment: I connected now with the windows.So there is no ISP problem. and I checked the firefox for proxy.No proxy is set. I have chromum too and I have this problem yet.

Comment: Can you change your IP? Reboot wireless router or access point? What is between you and internet? I think that is a filter router-side

Comment: Me-wireless modem-ISP

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is set to work offline.

For example in Firefox under File > Work offline.
Untick "Work offline" to resolve this.

Comment: :O .the problem is not just for browser. wget, update and etc have this problem so.