# Web browsers: HTTP not working in ubuntu 18.04 but HTTPS does

Tags: 18.04, https, url

I've never seen such thing before.

In ubuntu 18.04 LTS almost after 6 months, I have problem in loading HTTP urls in Firefox, Chrome even by wget. But I have no problem with same urls in HTTPS mode. Ping also works for the same urls.

However this problem not seen in other devices connected to same network!

Any help appreciated...

**Update**
I have a solution for this that's not intresting (actually headache):

1. In firefox from `Preferences > privacy > View Certificates > Delete All Server Certificates`.
2. Reboot the Ubuntu 18.04
3. For limited time everything working fine, but after visiting one of my websites with SSL (https), all urls with http stop working!

I think this problem related to websites with self-signed certificates, however these websites doesn't have similar problems in other devices.

Hope somebody knows the reason...

**Updated**:
Today I faced with another strange issue.

I've setup `Wifi hotspot` using my `Android` mobile with *4G data network* & my laptop conncted to mentioned hotspot.
Everything worked **fine**, but changing **hotspot** to **USB tethering** caused `http` stopped working.
By switching back to **hotspot** the problem gone!

Comment: Do your web browsers give you any kind of error, or do they just hang and eventually give up? If they give an error, please output it here.

Comment: They just hang and waiting and after timeout show this page can not be displayed.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo iptables-save`?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux `*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
`

Comment: What about `sudo ufw status`?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux `Status: inactive `

Comment: Can you do `telnet google.com 80`?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux Yes. `Connected to google.com`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install -f`? I've managed to conclude that the issue is not the local firewall since `telnet` works. I'm not an expert in this, but I think the problem is a corrupt library.

Comment: Yes, I did. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: This is a shot in the dark ... If you follow [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/104115/606758) does it all start working in Firefox?

Comment: It's not firefox specified issue. It's same for chrome and any other browser.

Comment: Does /etc/services contain this line?http            80/tcp          www             # WorldWideWeb HTTP

Comment: Do you have any kind of proxy active?

Comment: @AndreasHartmann Yes, `/etc/services` has that line. Sometimes I'm using `sshuttle`. But I've used it in `ubuntu 14.04` and I don't have any similar problem.

Comment: Can you post the output of

```wget -vvv https://www.google.com```

and

```wget -vvv http://langid.net/```

Or any other verbose wget with a https and a http that doesn't work?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato It was OK for your links: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK`. But for another website with https & SSL `ERROR: cannot verify example.com's certificate, issued by `

Comment: There must be a problem with your certificate authorities.

Try 

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Actually since 2 days ago (before your comment), I didn't see this problem. I'm waiting it'll happen again and I'll try your advice.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Today it happened again and I re-installed ca-certificates, but it has no effect. Also I review all comments for double-check sake, but nothing new. So like before removed server certificates, reboot and everything works again after a game :(

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. There was URL filtering (parental control) enabled on the wifi router with some blocked URL's on port 80.
Strange behavior, no matter what URL I add in the router for port 80, It would block all http traffic to ubuntu on cloud. 
It would also block http traffic when I had no rules but still have url filtering enabled.

When I add a url with https/tcp443 alone (without any port 80 blocked) then http traffic works or it also works with url filtering completely disabled...stupid.